# Equivalent for 'event of VHDL on Verilog - Synthetizable

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I need an equivalent for 'event of VHDL using Verilog.

This is an example to convert from VHDL to Verilog(Note: I need both posedge and negedge in the same porcess):

```
process (CLK, I) begin

 if (I'event and I = 1) then  //posedge
   x <= x + 1;
 elsif (I'event and I = 0)  //negedge
   x <= c + 2;
 end if;

 if (CLK'event and CLK = 1) // posedge
  a <= b + 1;
 end if;
```

end process;

Comment: To have both posedge and negedge in the same process seems like a strange requirement. It it definitely not synthesizable in Verilog or VHDL, and you your example certainly does not require it to be in one process. Verilog does not have a 'event attribute, however, depnding on what functionality you are really after, the are ways of achieving similar behaviors. SystemVerilog might have more to help you (.triggered method), but would still like to see more explanation.

Comment: Can you use an always block and put the signals you are looking for in your sensitivity list?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just take a stab at rewriting the code.

It appears that you have 2 separate things going on here. You have the assignment of a and the assignment of x. Assignment of a is based off the clock and assignment of x is based off of I.

```
always @(clk) begin
    if (posedge clk)
        a <= b + 1;
end

always @(in_i) begin
    if (posedge in_i)
        x <= x + 1;
    else if (negedge in_i)
        x <= c + 2;
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this usage of `posedge`/`negedge` is a syntax error.